# Like [Inject] attribute from Ninject, what is the equivalent in autofac?

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

I am new to the Autofac. I know that with Autofac, I need to register these properties like this:[Property Injection](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection). And I am looking for something in Autofac just like [Inject] attribute in Ninject.
Like this:

```
[Inject]
public Interface Someproperty { get; set; }
```

Can something like this be done with Autofac?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofac doesn't use attributes. Just make the properties you want injected public and ensure they have a `set` and Autofac does the rest.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the type you want the properties wired up
builder.RegisterType<YourType>().PropertiesAutowired();

// You have to register the thing you want injected to - the value of the property
// and it has to be registered to expose the type of the property. So if the property
// being injected is type `Interface` then make sure you say that here.
builder.RegisterType<AClass>().As<Interface>();
```

If you really, really want to control which properties get injected via attribute - which I don't recommend, because it's not great practice to have DI-related stuff intertwined with your business logic - [there is a working example in the Autofac repo in the form of a unit test](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/10c48117bb7c2ef42879409b03c6d981591487e8/test/Autofac.Specification.Test/Features/PropertyInjectionTests.cs#L262). That example shows you how to create your own custom attribute and use a custom Autofac property selector to only wire up properties that have the custom attribute.